# Close gap between DIVs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I close the gap between `DIV B` and `DIV C1 & DIV C2`?

I read that the `.row` is meant to be used inside a `container`. Since the `container` has padding to adjust the negative margin in the `.row`. But there is a margin between `DIV B` and `DIV C1 & DIV C2` though I'm not using `.row`?

```css
.fff {
  background-color: #088da5;
}
.ggg {
  background-color: #fbe9fa;
}
.iii {
  background-color: #8b7d6b;
}
.jjj {
  background-color: #9e0b0f;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-3 col-md-2 fff">DIV A</div>
  <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6 col-md-8 ggg">DIV B</div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
    <div class="jjj">DIV C1</div>
    <div class="iii">DIV C2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s1we183h/)

Comment: that's from your grid

Comment: @cjm628:thanks. how can I avoid it so that there won't be a gap between `DIV B` and `DIV C1 & DIV C2`?

Comment: That's a padding not a margin. You styled C1 and C2 `div` *inside* the bootstrap div hence the white padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap columns have gaps between them, to separate elements. You can use `.row` class inside your cols to avoid that gap, like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/s1we183h/8/).

```css
.fff {
  background-color: #088da5;
}
.ggg {
  background-color: #fbe9fa;
}
.iii {
  background-color: #8b7d6b;
}
.jjj {
  background-color: #9e0b0f;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-3 col-md-2 fff">DIV A</div>
  <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6 col-md-8 ggg">DIV B</div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="jjj">DIV C1</div>
      <div class="iii">DIV C2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I suggest also removing the "row" class from the main container. Its negative margins cause a horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: @showdev: why remove only form the main container? Won't that affect `DIV C1 and DIV C2`?

Comment: In bootstrap cols _must_ be inside rows. To avoid the negative margin you must use `.container` class, as [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro) says

Comment: @Choma thanks. So at the very top `<div class="row">` should be replaced by `<div class="container">`?

Comment: @Beki, your grids should be like: `.container` -> `.row`'s -> `.col-*`'s

Comment: @Choma thanks once again. So `col-` are wrapped inside `.rows` and all `.row` inside a `.container`. Does this mean there should be one `.container` for a page?

Comment: @Beki, yes, you should use `.container` or `.container-fluid`, as in the docs link I posted above.

Comment: @Choma I just added a `container` and there's space now on either side. Is that normal? How do I remove/reduce them?

Comment: I found the solution to this. When you add a .container-fluid class, it adds a horizontal padding of 15px, and the same will be removed when you add a .row class as a child element by the negative margin set on row.